# What race conditions and consequences will it be if thread-unsafe collection is used

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a general question that I cannot quite understand.

What race conditions and consequences will it be if thread-unsafe collection is used?

For example, java.util.HashSet is not thread safe. So what are the kind of race conditions and consequences? Could someone list these and provide some detailed explanation?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes: you might get race conditions and be thread-unsafe.

Comment: Anything... Depends on collection. You are effectively asking, what is a race condition.

Comment: @MitchWheat and hyde, please don't repeat what i said. i wanted to know concrete examples of bad stuff that could happen. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Say your collection has `{A, B, C}`.

Thread 1 tries to add D.
Thread 2 tries to add E.

You could (for example) end up with `{A, B, C, D}`, `{A, B, C, E}`, or `{A, B, C, D, E}`.

Comment: so why would it be problem though? two threads add to the collection, fine...?

Comment: It would be a problem because (presumably, depending on your application) only one of these is correct.  You could drop data and not know about it.  A particularly bad example: imagine each of these letters represents a customer account that needs to be reimbursed.  Would it be okay to just *not* reimburse someone because your collection wasn't threadsafe?

Answer (score 1):

Take an `ArrayList` for example. Let's say that the ArrayList has an elements as such: `[A,B,C,D]`. Now say two threads get the first element and one tries to set it to `A.operation()` and the other tries to set it to `A.anotherOperation()`. You could get one of several possible outcomes:

```
[A.operation(),B,C,D]
[A.anotherOperation(),B,C,D]
[A.operation().anotherOperation(),B,C,D]
[A.anotherOperation().operation(),B,C,D]
```

If you don't understand how race conditions work, do some research. For example, read [this.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html)

Comment: It's even worse! you could see a version of `A` with only some of its data; for instance, if `A` is itself an `ArrayList`, you might see half-broken information for it. There are a _ton_ of things that can go wrong.